# How to set notifications?

Tags: android, webview, feed

Please help me. I created an Android application for my website.

Now I want to notify the users when I update/upload new contents to my website.

I mean to say when I update something to my webpage, the users who are using my applicationm ust get the notification that:
* "... is added to... "
* "check out now..."

I hope you understand what I am trying to say.
Sorrry for my bad English

I.e.: just like a newspaper application on adding new news to webpage.
Users get notification that "Something happens"

Comment: seach for `android rss feed`

Comment: Notification is a big subject. You need to search about it and see how it is implemented for Android applications. Then if you have specific question, you can ask here to get help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for you to add Firebase to your application.

Then you'll need [Firebase Cloud Messaging Service](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
```

Add this service to your manifest

```
<service
        android:name=".model.notifications.NotificationService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And create your service

```
public class NotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

  @Override public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    Timber.d("Message received [" + remoteMessage + "]");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1410, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentTitle("Notification!")
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (notificationManager != null) {
      notificationManager.notify(1410, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
  }
}
```

If you go to Notifications panel in your Firebase dashboard, you can send instant notifications to a specific user or every user who use your app.

Comment: I know that but for that each time I have to send the notifications

But I wana to know is there any way.... 

So that notification automatically send...

Comment: For this each time I have log-in to my firebase account then send notification to end users      right...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542073/send-notification-automatically-from-firebase

Answer (score 0):

You can use something to make push notification such as Firebase.
here's a link you can start from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)